# What is the Visual Studio Project setting to prevent an application from launching after a build or rebuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a home grown project (https://github.com/andybantly/MFC-Fractal) that I have been working on since the Visual Studio 2005/2008 days.  I just recently put it in Git.  Its home is on CodeProject.

I am not sure when this started (maybe 10 years ago...) but when I migrated my application to the latest version of Visual Studio, new/odd behavior injected itself into the code generation step.  The IDE has somehow decided that when I build the source that I really wanted to build and run the source.  This is somewhat annoying, especially during a batch rebuild all.

I am looking for helpful suggestions on configuring the IDE to prevent this behavior.  It never used to do this out of the box.

Is it a show stopper?  Absolutely not.  Is it annoying?  Depends on the side of bed I woke up on.

Comment: Muscle memory makes one press F5 to build, instead of Ctrl+Shift+B.

Comment: Hans, it is only F5 if you have the proper language kb shortcuts.  However, that was not my question.  I am quite aware of 'F5'.  My problem is that when I press 'F7', Visual Studio compiles, and then launches the application as if I had pressed 'F5'  This is not what I want.